# GetLegendGraphic with Filtered Range Rules

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, getlegendgraphic, rule

I have a style with several rules that include range filters. I'm having a hard time getting the appropriate legend graphic for a specific record.

For example, a soil depth of 3 should return the legend icon for "Shallow", but when passed as a rule, I get *"Specified style does not contains a rule named 3"*, an accurate error, the rule's name for that value is "Shallow". If I try to pass it as a featuretype, I get the full legend and not just the icon for that rule.

Surely there's a way to do this in Geoserver, is my style simply configured in a round about way?

**Style w/ 1 rule for simplicity**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
<sld:NamedLayer>
  <sld:Name>soil_depth</sld:Name>
  <sld:UserStyle>
    <sld:Name>soil_depth</sld:Name>
    <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
      <sld:Name>soil_depth</sld:Name>
      <sld:Rule>
        <sld:Name>Shallow</sld:Name>
        <sld:Title>Shallow</sld:Title>
        <ogc:Filter>
          <ogc:And>
            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>depth</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
              <ogc:PropertyName>depth</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
          </ogc:And>
        </ogc:Filter>
        <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>512000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
        <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
          <sld:Fill>
            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#68B7FF</sld:CssParameter>
            <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">.4</sld:CssParameter>
          </sld:Fill>
        </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
      </sld:Rule>
    </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
  </sld:UserStyle>
</sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

**Request w/ rule**

> https://domain.com/geoserver/workspace/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&services=WMS&version=1.1.1&format=image%2Fpng&layer=soil_depth&transparent=true&legend_options=forceLabels%3Aoff&height=20&width=20&rule=3

**Response w/ rule -- this makes sense**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "https://gsdev.pivvot.com/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >
    <ServiceException>
      Specified style does not contains a rule named 3
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

**Request w/ featuretype**

> https://domain.com/geoserver/workspace/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&services=WMS&version=1.1.1&format=image%2Fpng&layer=soil_depth&transparent=true&legend_options=forceLabels%3Aoff&height=20&width=20&featuretype=3

**Response w/ featuretype -- does not make sense**

[image: Full legend]

**Desired response**

[image: Shallow legend]

Comment: can you add the actual request you are making for the legend graphic with the results and relevant log section for the one that doesn't work. Also you may want to look at [PropertyIsBetween](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html) filters

Comment: Added. PropertyIsBetween does seem like a cleaner option going forward. I don't think it will change how this call is being made, though.

Comment: I would try with `rule=Shallow`

Comment: Right... I don't have Shallow. I have the actual value, which is 3. The data doesn't know that 3 equates to "Shallow", that's just a label we slap on the map.

Comment: Using the Geoserver tutorials, I have a record with 3000000 as the value for persons, and I want to return just that legend icon. My question is: is it possible to do this? https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/tutorial.html

Comment: But you have to provide either the rule name or an XML feature type, not a value. I think you need to explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to display the legend icon for a specific data point. It sounds like it is not possible to do with GetLegendGraphic, so that's answer enough.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding your use case, legends apply to the whole map not a single feature.

Comment: It's a separate application entirely, this is not for displaying on the map.